# How to include a subtemplate in a Puppet template

Tags: erb, puppet

I'm trying to include a subtemplate in a template for one of my Puppet modules. Here's how I do the include in my base template:

```
<%
  def import(fname)
    erb =
      File.open(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/" + fname) { |fp| ERB.new(fp.read) }
    erb.run
  end
%>

<%= import("subtemplate.erb") %>
```

This works fine if I render it with erb command-line tool. However, during the Puppet run the import is silently ignored, i.e. the base template is rendered with a blank line where the rendered subtemplate should be. There are no errors generated.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about:

```
 <%= scope.function_template("subtemplate.erb") %>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Your suggestion did not work immediately but I was able to build up on it and ended up with: `<%= scope.function_template(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/" + "subtemplate.erb") %>` The reason I had to prepend the pwd is likely because the original template was nested in a couple of subdirectories within the modules/templates directory.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I have a quick question; Is there a way to avoid the header comment of the subtemplate.erb file getting appended to calling erb? What would be the format we need to use for the license header in subtemplate.erb for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

argument to the function needs to be an array (>=puppet-3):

```
scope.function_foo(["bar"])
```

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html#using-functions-within-templates