# How to include a subtemplate in a puppet template using future parser

Tags: templates, puppet, upgrade, erb

During our upgrade up from Puppet 3.5.7 and after piecing together information from:

[How to include a subtemplate in a Puppet template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551717/how-to-include-a-subtemplate-in-a-puppet-template?newreg=8971322106b24a9aa0d47fdc0af1d542)

I could reference a subtemplate with some variable in the filename like so:

```
<%= scope.function_template([File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/" + "subtemplate_" + @oscar_package + ".properties.erb"]) %>
```

After enabling the future parser I get the following error:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call,
>   Failed to parse template
>   oscar_mysql_tomcat/context/oscar_demo15.properties.e rb:
>     Filepath: org/jruby/RubyString.java
>     Line: 1172
>     Detail: can't convert nil into String
>   at  /etc/puppet/environments/development/modules/oscar_mysql_tomcat/manifests/context.pp:11:18
>   on node bcmdit-devel-536-puppetclient Warning: Not using cache on
>   failed catalog Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

It is failing at the resolution of @oscar_package, how do I do it the future parser way?

**Update 1**

After consulting:
https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.4/lang_template_erb.html#calling-puppet-functions-from-templates
It seems that I should be using scope.call_function:

```
<%= scope.call_function('template', [File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/" + "subtemplate_" + @oscar_package + ".properties.erb"]) %>
```

This yields the same error.

Comment: You mention future parser, so this is Puppet 3.x you are currently on? That is very obsolete, so upgrading could be the first step here if it is an option.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am upgrading Puppet and part of the process is switching to the use the future parser in preparation for Puppet4 to find where code changes are necessary.

Comment: Ok; so since `@oscar_package` is being instantiated in Ruby as `nil`, there is something going wrong with the binding from the Puppet function call to `template`. This means the problem is most likely in your manifest code. Could we see the relevant part of that?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks, that got me on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

The class I am using is a child of another class with the oscar_package variable defined.

It was solved by passing the variable to the subclass so it could be accessed directly within the scope from where the function in the erb template was called.

So in the init.pp definition the relevant code is:

```
if $sys_report::active_database_context_list != "" {
  oscar_mysql_tomcat::context { "active_${sys_report::active_database_context_list}":
    db_name               => "$sys_report::active_database_context_list",
    oscar_package         => "$oscar_package",
    oscar_package_build   => "$oscar_package_build",
    role                  => "link",
    tomcat_site_seal      => "$tomcat_site_seal",
    tomcat_host_fqdn      => "$tomcat_host_fqdn",
    tomcat_port           => "$tomcat_port",
    twitter_feed          => "$twitter_feed",
    require               => File['/etc/sys-report.var'],
  }
}
```